# Como preencher múltiplos campos de texto automaticamente quando o input text principal receber um valor e perder o foco?

Tags: php, sql

Tenho um BD com as tabelas *livros* e *empréstimos*. Na tabela *empréstimos*, dentre outras colunas, tenho uma para colocar o título do livro e o código deste livro. A ideia é que, ao inserir o código do referido livro e tirar o foco desse respectivo input, o campo subsequente já seja preenchido com o título do livro em questão (nesse caso, tanto o código quanto o título são oriundos da tabela *livros*).

Eu até consigo um certo resultado quando ponho um valor estático para teste, mas, mesmo pesquisando materiais a respeito de como fazer isso de modo dinâmico, ainda não consegui compreender a lógica por trás desta questão.

A propósito, usei a palavra "múltiplos" no título, porque pretendo aplicar o mesmo raciocínio desta questão para fazer o mesmo com outros inputs presentes na página na qual estou trabalhando.

Como proceder nesta situação?

```html
<?php 
$beta = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT titulo FROM livros WHERE codigo_livro='3'"); 

        if (count($beta) == 1 ) {
            $b = mysqli_fetch_array($beta);
            $titulo_livroB = $b['titulo'];
        }

?>

    <input required type="number" name="codigo_livro" placeholder="Insira o código do livro..." value="">
    <input required type="text" name="titulo_livro" placeholder="A ser preenchido automaticamente de acordo com o valor do campo acima." value="<?php echo $titulo_livroB; ?>">
```

Comment: Você está tentando fazer com que a ao usuário interagir com a página, ela atualize os dados dinamicamente? Se for isso, dá uma pesquisada em **Ajax**. O PHP age no `back end`, enquanto o usuário a interagir, no `front end`. No caso do navegador, seria feita uma requisição em Javascript para o servidor, que retornaria os dados e o `front end` faria a dinâmica da coisa. Em contra partida, utilizando somente PHP, você poderia enviar os dados via `POST` ou `GET` e a própria página seria atualizada toda vez que o formulário fosse enviado, trazendo as novas informações.

Comment: Consegui fazê-lo funcionar, @WeslleyAraújo! Encontrei um material que me ajudou muito nisso, e, de fato, envolve o AJAX. Muito obrigado pela dica!